# List of listeners in AEM 6 for Touch UI

Tags: aem

Can anyone please help me in getting the list of listeners in Touch UI of AEM 6?

I know one event as `keypress`, but I would also want to know the event which gets triggered when we change the value from a drop-down in the AEM Form Field of Touch UI.

Answer (score 0):

Only some of the Extjs Listener events are in AEM 6's Granite UI.
one you mentioned is `keypress` event. Some other events like `foundation-contentloaded` are mentioned on [this page](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/touch-ui/granite-reference.html).

other then these, you could use `cls` property on AEM components and specify the event handlers yourself via the class.

```
$('.my-select-class').on('change' , function(event){
    console.log("Handling Event " , event);
})
```